# PHP get params from function inside of Namespace

Tags: php, reflection

I'm trying to get the params (names) of a function that is stored within a namespace and class. I've tried `ReflectionFunction`, but I can only make that work without namespaces and classes. The function I'm trying to call is non-static, which doesn't make it much easier.

```
namespace app\http;

class Test {
   public function func(User $user, $id) {
     return $user;
   } 
}
```

I'm trying to get "user" and "id" from here. Does someone have a suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error you are facing and cannot resolve? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php

```php
$ref = new ReflectionMethod(\app\http\Test::class, "func");

foreach ($ref->getParameters() as $param) {
    echo $param->getName();
}
```

`$ref->getParameters()` returns an array of `ReflectionParameter` classes which allows you to get more information than just the name; https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php

You could also use the string value for the class: `"\app\http\Test"` but the special `::class` constant is more reliable when in different namespaces (if not using the fully qualified name).

> The special ::class constant allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile time, this is useful for namespaced classes